# Moodle Drupal Integration SSO

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, moodle

I'm using drupal 7.41 and moodle 2.7. My intention is to integrating both the sites. I need to achieve the SSO between these two. I installed [moodle_sso](https://www.drupal.org/project/moodle_sso) on drupal side and [drupalservices](https://github.com/cannod/moodle-drupalservices) on moodle side. How ever I logged in drupal, it automatically logs into the moodle side. When I give log out on moodle side, automatically log outs from drupal side.

The problem is here, When I give log out on drupal side, moodle doesn't log out the user.

I needs this to be work. Because I used the Drupal as main login/logout frontend. I had several user in my drupal side. When the first user enters to moodle everything is fine. When the second user login to moodle it shows the details of first user only. Any solution for this would be appreciable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is a -1 but here goes. I've done this through Shibboleth and the Shibboleth plugins for both Moodle and Drupal. You can either point to an LDAP or one of the instances DBs for authentication and this will allow you to keep separate attribute structures.